# Most simple way to make an multiple INSERT on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code.

```
elseif ($numerodeprocesos == 4) {
    $upd2= "INSERT INTO juan (ciudadh)
    VALUES ('$ciudadh')";
    $upd3= "INSERT INTO juan (ciudadh)
   VALUES ('$ciudadh')";
    $upd4= "INSERT INTO juan (ciudadh)
   VALUES ('$ciudadh')";
   $upd5= "INSERT INTO juan (ciudadh)
    VALUES ('$ciudadh')";
   $upd6= "INSERT INTO juan (ciudadh)
   VALUES ('$ciudadh')";
mysql_query($upd2)or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_query($upd3)or die( mysql_error() );
    mysql_query($upd4)or die( mysql_error() );
        mysql_query($upd5)or die( mysql_error() );
            mysql_query($upd6)or die( mysql_error() );

}
```

But, what is the most simple way do to that? I mean it is possyble to do it in one single mysql_query?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/insert.html) gives you the syntax for `INSERT` in mysql.

Comment: But all these insert the same variable `$ciudadh`, so why would you need to keep inserting the same values? Looks more like an over-writing code.

Comment: Yes, @Javier Brooklyn is just the same value. And I need over writing that same values for one specific reason into my code (its important to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a single insert statement that inserts multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO juan (ciudadh)
    VALUES ('$ciudadh'), ('$ciudadh'), ('$ciudadh'), ('$ciudadh');
```

See also: [`INSERT Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)